# PHP: Check if Process is running with pid

Tags: php, linux

I want to verify with php whether a process, let's say "gedit", is running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pidof gedit` and checking whether the the first value of the returned Array is an interger:

```
exec("pidof gedit",$response);
if (is_numeric($response[0])){
    echo $response[0];
} 
else {
    echo "no response";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system doesn't have `pidof` you can use `ps aux | grep gedit` which if it returns more than one row of output, would mean you have an active process.  I say more than one row, as you will always see a row of output for the `ps aux | grep gedit` process itself.  Note that this might also be more useful if you need regular expression type of searching for the executing process.